# Почему страница недоступна для Googlebot?

Tags: seo, индексация, google-search

Googlebot при проверке определенной страницы выдает "Временно недоступно". Сама страница доступна через браузер и при проверке сторонними сервисами выдает ответ - 200 ОК. Думал может хостинг заблокировал бота по IP.Но при проверке других страниц ботом проблем не возникло. Проверил время ответа сервера: 150мс. Так что проблема и не в этом. Из-за чего это может быть? Может кто-то уже сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Comment: Думаю, без ссылки ответить что-либо будет трудно

Comment: @andreymal Вот ссылка: https://www.flatour.com/dailyrent/new/4/39/ru/

Comment: А где вы смотрите что статус был 404?

Comment: На Search console при попытке просмотеть как Googlebot выдает "Временно недоступно". Но нигде не выдает 404

Answer (score -1):

### Ошибки сканирования

Если Ваша страница попала в категорию **"Ошибки сканирования"**, это означает что бот не смог ее загрузить в определенный период времени. Возможные причины:

1. Сайт был очень загружен во время загрузки страницы ботом.
2. Ваша страница пере создавалась (удалялась и после заново создавалась в CMS) и в этот период бот пытался ее загрузить.

### Просмотреть как Googlebot

Также в **"Search Console"** от Gooogle есть функционал для просмотра страниц как **GoogleBot** воспользуйтесь ним и добавьте результат.

### Поправьте верстку страницы

Ваша страница не является ***правильно сверстанной***, она не распознается как **HTML** документ.

### robots.txt

Проверьте файл ***robots.txt*** в корне сайта.

Comment: это общие рекомендации, а не ответ

Comment: @AndrioSkur Алгоритмы постоянно меняются, не кто не даст Вам точный ответ, так как гугл сам себе не враг. В этом и смысл алгоритма, повышать рейтинг только качественным сайтам.